# Redirecting ASP.NET MVC Core client side validation error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, asp.net-core-mvc, materialize, unobtrusive-validation

I want to use TagHelpers and ASP.NET MVC CORE server generated client side validation (via Jquery Validation and Unobtrusive Validation), but unfortunately I can't use the default span element that is generated. Example:

```
        <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Test" class="validate-form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input asp-for="Id" class="validate" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Id"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">CREATE</button>
        </form>
```

Will generate:

```
<form class="validate-form" action="/Opportunity/1" method="post" 
novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input class="validate valid" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" value="1" aria-describedby="Id-error" aria-invalid="false">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">CREATE</button>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="...">
</form>
```

But I don't want span, I want to use [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) design components which needs this markup to be in place:

```
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="Id" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="Id" data-error="error message">Email</label>
    </div>
```

What I need, is the ASP.NET MVC CORE client side validation messages to be redirected to this label and it's data-error attribute. I made a configuration for this:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'invalid',
    validClass: "valid",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element)
            .parent('.input-field')
            .find("label[for='" + element.attr("id") + "']")
            .attr('data-error', error.text());
    }
});
```

But unfortunately it seems it's ignored because of all of the unobtrusive javascript added by ASP.NET. Does anyone know a better solution or fix for my solution? Any answer will be welcomed! And yeah, I tried making custom TagHelper, couldn't find a way how it could solve my problem.

Comment: To change the error element, you'll need to use `errorElement` option.  I don't see that in your `setDefaults()` method.  However, the plugin's default is `label` and if Unobtrusive is already changing that into a `span`, your only option would be to not use Unobtrusive in the first place.  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorelement